# Specifying threshold to use for h2o steam prediction service

Tags: h2o

Using `h2o steam`'s prediction service for a deployed model, the default threshold that seems to be used by the prediction service is the max f1 threshold. However, in my case I would like the be able to use other thresholds (as displayed by the model when built in `h2o flow`) (eg. max f2 or max accuracy thresholds) like these.

[image]

Is there a way to set these thresholds in `steam`?

Looking at the inspector on the prediction service page, seems to shows that the logic for the predictor is from a script called "predict.js" (see below):

[image]

But I can't find where in the `steam` launch directory (running from local host based on [these](http://docs.h2o.ai/steam/latest-stable/steam-docs/Installation.html#start-steam-locally) instructions) these files are (doing a file search in this directory for anything named "predict.js" returns nothing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe for POJOs there's no way to change it as it's hardcoded. Don't know the answer for MOJOs.

Comment: Since the models in `steam` project seem like they can only come from running `h2o flow` cluster I guess there is no way to change the hard-coding. But all (binomial) POJOS from `flow` seem to have a score0() function that takes some arguments and returns a prediction value. In this function there seems to be the threshold value used to get the max f1 threshold prediction (near the bottom of this function in my experience). From here I think I can modify the threshold value manually, but is there then a way to use this new .java POJO in the `steam` server?

Comment: Also, is there a way to access the predict.js file shown in the post screenshot so that it can be used instead in the `steam` instance?

Comment: No I don't think you can change it. I think it's possible that you can change the threshold in the POJO Java file and then build a prediction service from that. Can't say if you can get that into Steam, but you can use it with the stand-alone Prediction Service Builder. As for `predict.js` you can find that here https://github.com/h2oai/steam/tree/master/prediction-service-builder/src/main/webapp/extra Note that in there you can't change any thresholds anyway.

Comment: For the `predict.js` file, I know where it is within the raw source of the github steam repo. (https://github.com/h2oai/steam) file structure, but I am running `steam` from the the official download page (https://www.h2o.ai/download/) (for linux) using these instructions (http://docs.h2o.ai/steam/latest-stable/steam-docs/Installation.html#installing-and-starting-steam-on-a-local-machine) not from a git clone of the source repo. And from within this unzipped directory there is no `predict.js` file that I can find.

Comment: Steam starts and uses the Prediction Service Builder, and predict.js is inside of that. It couldn't build prediction services otherwise.

Comment: Doing a named search in the dir. that was unzipped when I downloaded `steam` from official website exactly following these instructions (http://docs.h2o.ai/steam/latest-stable/steam-docs/Installation.html#id1), does not show any files called `predict.js`. I agree that the prediction service must need this file, but looking in the dir. that I am running `steam` from, I can't tell where that file is. I know where it is and how to get to it if I were running `steam` from a git clone of the source repo. (https://github.com/h2oai/steam/blob/master/DEVEL.md), but not from the official download.

Comment: Actually, just now I'm guessing that the prediction service is compressed in a .jar file or something, so you'd be right that it would be inaccessible except running from the source.

Comment: The prediction service builder is a stand-alone web application that is distributed with Steam. If you unpack the Steam download, you'll find it in a file called `ROOT.war`. Steam starts this web application. Now if you look inside `ROOT.war` you'll find `predict.js` in `extra/predict.js`. It is indeed a jar file, in this case called a war file because it's a web application.